# Is refactoring of tests/spec a good idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, refactoring, tdd, rspec

When I see in my test code specs like this for every controller:

```
it "#new displays input controls for topic title and keywords" do

  ensure_im_signed_in
  get :new

  assert_response :success
  assert_select "input#topic_title"
  assert_select "input#topic_keywords_input"
  assert assigns :topic
end
```

I want to refactor it and replace with some one-liner like this:

```
its_new_action_displays_input_form :topic, %w(input#topic_title input#topic_keywords_input)
```

and implementation:

```
def its_new_Action_displays_input_form field, inputs
  it "#new displays input controls for #{inputs.join ", "}" do
    ensure_im_signed_in
    get :new
    assert_response :success
    for css in inputs
      assert_select css
    end
    assert assigns field
  end
end
```

What are the advantages of either keeping verbose version or refactoring to terser version?

I see only problem with refactored version is that RSpec does not show backtrace for the failed test.

Comment: You might find this video interesting. In this video, Gerard Meszaros talks about refactoring unit tests, and talks about the reasons for doing it. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pq6LHFM4JvE Gerard Meszaros is author of 'xUnit Test Patterns - Refactoring Test Code'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My very first job out of college was updating a set of unit tests. They were about 7 years old, with many deprecated methods being used. It took me eight months (there were a lot of them!) and I still didn't finish the job. However, I did manage to reduce the file size to about 1/3rd the original size and greatly simplify the work by refactoring much of it, and that helped speed up the work.

So, I would definitely encourage refactoring!

Answer (score 2):

The biggest question we always ask is "who is testing the tests?"  You should definately go with refactoring your unit tests where ever you are and at whatever stage you are as it helps reduce the complexity.  Reducing the complexity within your unit tests will yield the same benefits as reducing the complexity within your code base.  I can see very little reason not to do it and many reasons to do it.

Comment: @wheaties, I think we should go with procedure: 1. run your test (GREEN) 2. temporary break your production code (RED) 3. change your test (RED) 4. restore your production code (GREEN?)

Comment: Why temporary break your production code? To go RED, just change your test so it will fail.

Comment: My very first job out of college was updating a set of unit tests.  They were about 7 years old, with many deprecated methods being used.  It took me eight months (there were a *lot* of them!) and I still didn't finish the job.  So, I would definitely encourage refactoring!

Comment: @Ethel Evans, you'd better put this as answer :)

Comment: @Guilherme Oenning, Because it should not become RED after refactoring - code and test expected to be correct. So to verify that test is correct we break the code to see, if the test is able to detect the code defect

Comment: @Alexey I understand your point now because your not talking about TDD/BDD, right? Because on a Test-First approach, you can't really change your production code without a broken test. You first change your test so it will test a new behaviour that you're expecting and it will fail, then you make it pass by fixing your production code. Do you agree? Or I misunderstood what you said?

Comment: I'm going to refactor (change) my tests, i'm not going to change my production code at all. I just need to check that the modified tests are still verifying the correctness of the production code

Comment: Thanks, Alexey - I just got back from vacation and posted as an answer below.

Comment: @Alexey I'd probably refactor tests in this order: 1. run test (GREEN), 2. change/refactor your test (GREEN), 3. temporarily break production code (RED), 4. restore production code (GREEN). Just to keep things separate, and always have one verifiable stake in the ground which is ensuring the correct behaviour at all times. To avoid changing both the production code and the test at the same time, like you did in your step 2. and 3. Not a huge issue though, as the temporary break in prod code is controlled and bounded.

Answer (score 1):

You refactor the spec because of the same reasons that you refactor everything else: It will make your application – be it you production app or tests suit – runs faster.

Also, refactoring a piece of code makes you think about the intention that you had to writing such a thing. This increases your comprehension of the problem and will make you more capable of solving other problems in the same application.

Yet I would strongly disagree about your refactoring. You see, when you are watching a spec you want to see fast and clear what are you testing. If you move the asserts to other place, you are hitting your self, because you need to go and find where did you put that thing.

I suggest you that never move the asserts out of your spec. Even if they are repeated. That's fine. It remarks the intention, so you never forget what you want to test.

Instead, focus your refactoring on boiler code.

For example, you are testing a form and to get to that page you need to click many links. A first approach would be to put everything in the spec. A lot of click_link.

I refactoring of such code will be put the whole bunch of click_link to a before(:each). Use Context as well, to clarify.

Like this:

```
feature "Course" do
  context "Loged in" do
    before(:each) do
      school = School.make!
      switch_to_subdomain(school)
    end

    context "In the new course form" do
      before(:each) do
        click_link("Asignaturas")
        click_link("Nueva asignatura")
      end

      scenario "New course" do               
        fill_in(:name, :with => "Matematicas")
        click_button("Create Course")
        page.has_content?("Asignatura creada").should == true
        dbSchool = School.find(school.id)         
        dbSchool.courses.count.should == 1
      end
          scenario "New course" do               
        fill_in(:name, :with => "")
        click_button("Create Course")
        page.has_content?("Asignatura creada").should == false
        dbSchool = School.find(school.id)         
        dbSchool.courses.count.should == 0
      end


    end
  end  
end
```

You see?  The boiler code is out of the specific spec. But let enough on the spec so that 7 month after that you can understand what you are testing. Never take away the asserts.

So my answer: Refactor Spec is not only a good idea, but a necessity. But don't mix refactoring with hiding code.

Comment: I cannot agree with your principle. If you had more complex checks than in your case, it would make sense to refactor out them to a function/mathcer. The problem with tests is that they touch different domains (UI interaction/verification, DB initialization/verification), thus it's difficult to work out concise and expressive enough DSL.

Comment: @Alexey I agree that moving the code to its own function would make it more concise. But I am willing to trade size for expressivity.

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed refactor your tests to remove duplication.  However, there are likely ways to do it that that keep the failure backtrace.

Rather than pulling everything out to a single method, you might do well to have a shared
`before(:each)` section for the common setup, and write your own matchers and/or assertions to combine the checks.